# DBContext as a pararameter to a long running task? Access to disposed closure

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-6

I have a warning that I am giving access to a disposed closure.
Yet I am not running my task asynchronously
[image]

The MakeConnect() is returning an Entity Framework Context.

Is this because I should not have a DBContext accessible by more than one thread?

I am using

```
using t = System.Threading.Tasks;
```

- I forgot to delete the line starting "var retval =  " from my code snippet.  but it is not relevant to my question.

Comment: Is it possible that "connect" will be disposed before CreateAppointments inside Task.Run is finished ?

Comment: how would that occur?

Comment: That error message because of variable "connect", you can see the blue underline. The right path would be "wait until Task.Run is finished", then you can dispose "connect".

Comment: I aren't running asynchronously so shouldn't the task run to completion before the connect is disposed?

Comment: You start CreateAppointment in a "Task.Run", it means you start it asnychronously.

Comment: My suggestion would be, put the whole "using" block inside Task.Run and not only CreateAppointments.

Comment: I was getting confused, I thought something only ran async if it was declared as async.  Care to write up your answer?

Comment: Not only declare it as "async". If you start your method inside Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew or Thread, then you start your method asynchronously. Async-await is only a new command from C# 6 (I think) and inside async-await is also create a new Task using Task.Run.

Comment: I think, your method "CreateAppointments" is already async, you dont need the line "t.Task.Run....", just use the line "var retval = CreateAppointments(...", and that is already async, because that method needs CancellationToken, to cancel the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and your error/warning message will be gone:

```
private static void CallCreateAppointments(IObjectSpace os)
{
  var config = HandyDefaults.GetConfig(os, EnumImportOrder.ReadyBy);
  using (var connect = MakeConnect(os))
  {
    var ct = new CancellationToken();

    // this method is already async, because it needs CancellationToken
    // to be able to cancel the task, just start it like this,
    // no need to start it inside Task.Run(...)
    var retval = CreateAppointments(connect, ct, null, config);
    // do whatever with retval
  }
}
```

Comment: actually the cancellation token was not needed since CreateAppointments is not async. Thus I fixed the parameters and moved the whole CallCreateAppointments to be inside a Run.


  t.Task.Run(() => { CreateAppointments( config); });

Comment: Ok, I don't know what is inside CreateAppointments. If CreateAppointments need CancellationToken, it means you can cancel the task inside CreateAppointments. It is also possible, only as input parameter but never used...:=)